# use jQuery with useEffect

Tags: jquery, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to set an interval for my materialize carousel home page. So I found this jQuery. although it's not working. it's telling that there is a problem with webpack.  Question is, is there a way to make this work ? or an alternative to make this auto play.  here is my code.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import img from "./img/pillowSlider1.jpg";
import img2 from "./img/pillowSlider2.jpg";
import img3 from "./img/pilowSlider3.jpg"
import $ from "jquery";

const Home = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        $('slider').slider({
            indicators: false,
            height: 1000,
            transaction: 500,
            interval: 6000
        })

    }, []);

    return (
        <section className="slider">
            <ul className="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src={img} alt=""/>
                    <div className="caption center-align">
                        <h2>Custom made pillows</h2>
                        <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                        <Link to="/pillows" className="btn btn-large red lighten-4">Learn More</Link>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src={img2} alt=""/>
                    <div className="caption left-align">
                        <h2>Make your couch or bed look pretty</h2>
                        <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                        <Link to="/pillows" className="btn btn-large red lighten-4">Learn More</Link>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src={img3} alt=""/>
                    <div className="caption right-align">
                        <h2>Bring your comfort to the next level</h2>
                        <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                        <Link to="/pillows" className="btn btn-large red lighten-4">Learn More</Link>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

please assist. Thank you

Comment: sorry but there's no reason to use an old fashioned jquery with react. there are 100 native sliders out there. hope that helps

Comment: Are you not using the Materialize slider? I don't recognise your markup. In any case, you don't need jQuery to use Materialize. https://materializecss.com/carousel.html#initialization

Comment: @ Sean Yes, but there is no autoplay option, with materializecss.com/carousel.html#initialization. The autoplay is mostly what I want. If there is someway to at that without jQuery that would be thew best !

Comment: Please note that your jquery selector is wrong.. should be `$('.slider')` (please note the dot)